# MVVMCross - Automatically register singleton in another assembly

Tags: mvvmcross

I have a service that resides in a different project from the core project (hence different assembly).

I can manually register the singleton with `RegisterSingleton<>()`

However I was hoping the standard linq query would pick it up for me: `CreatableTypes().EndingWith("Service").AsInterfaces().RegisterAsLazySingleton();`

The problem is creatable types appears only to look in the current assembly. What is the best way to use the reflection overload?

I looked at solutions for getting the assembly from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141121/how-to-get-the-assembly-system-reflection-assembly-for-a-given-type-in-net), but they do not work from within a PCL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CreateableTypes()` has an overload `CreateableTypes(Assembly assembly)` which you can use. To obtain the assembly where your service is residing from a PCL project, you should be able to use `GetTypeInfo().Assembly` on your service type (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19845144/650012) SO answer).

So, to conclude:

```
var assembly = typeof(ResidingInAnotherAssemblyService).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
CreatableTypes(assembly).EndingWith("Service").AsInterfaces().RegisterAsLazySingleton();
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew I needed the overload, but getting the assembly was the sticking point. Thanks for the `GetTypeInfo().Assembly` tip.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Anders answer. We simply add a static class in our (different) `PCL`.

```
public static class MvxBootstrap
{
    public static void Initialize()
    {
        typeof(MvxBootstrap).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.CreatableTypes()
            .EndingWith("Service")
            .AsInterfaces()
            .RegisterAsLazySingleton();

        typeof(MvxBootstrap).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.CreatableTypes()
            .EndingWith("Client")
            .AsInterfaces()
            .RegisterAsLazySingleton();
    }
}
```

Then in your `App.cs` in the core simply call `MvxBootstrap.Initialize();`