# C# Filestream denied access

Tags: c#, filestream

I'm trying to use C# to create a file, and read files back to fill out a rich text block. right now my problem is in creating/writing to the file.

```
FileStream fs = File.Create(@".\\tmp\" + fileName);
```

This is where I'm trying to write to. .\tmp\ exists, but when trying to write it it errors, saying

> .\tmp\filename access is denied

Answer (score 0):

The probably is that the user that is running the application probably doesn't have access to write to that directory.  The easiest way to test that would be to run your application as administrator you should have access to write to that directory then.

You might also want to consider writing to the current directory no matter what user who is running your application should at the very least have access to that directory

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
```

Comment: I am the one running the program, and the "." folder is located inside of my own user folder. I'm not sure why I wouldn't have access to it. I started up VS with admin rights and that didn't fix it either

Answer (score 0):

Probably you don't have access to the relative path.
To get your assembly directory:

```
private static string AssemblyDirectory
{
    get
    {
        string codeBase = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
        UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder(codeBase);
        string path = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Path);
        return Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
    }
}
```

Then

```
FileStream fs = File.Create(Path.Combine(AssemblyDirectory, fileName));
```

Comment: Why wouldn't I have access? That'd at least help me understand what's going on a bit. This is under "." which translates to something like

    `/users/[me]/source/repos..../app1/x86/debug/tmp/`

Which is under my user folder

Comment: I think that "." represents the directory where your assembly runs, but to find it better to use the function `AssemblyDirectory`.

Comment: I'm trying your code, but ```GetExecutingAssembly()``` seems to not be valid. I've got System.Reflectio. Everything else there doesn't mess up

Comment: `GetExecutingAssembly()` is in `System.Reflection.Assembly`. Which is your error?

Comment: With System.Reflection.Assembly imported, it's that reflection.assembly doesn't exist. without it, it's that GetExecutingAssembly is not contained in Assembly

Comment: I hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718232/assembly-getexecutingassembly-doesnt-exist-in-pcl?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) can help you.

Answer (score -1):

You are using a relative path which leads to a location which you don't have access to.

A possible solution could be to:

1. Create a folder C:/data and make sure you have read and write rights to that folder
2. change the code to

   ```
   string fileName = "file.txt";
   FileStream fs = File.Create(@"C:/data/" + fileName);
   ```

This should create a file under C:/data with the filename "file.txt", assuming you have the correct read and write rights.

If you want a relative path to the current user's root directory, use:

```
string currentUserDirectory = 
       Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
```

Comment: The relative file path leads to my own user directory. I know for a fact I have r/w access to that. I've tried using "C:/tmp/" before after making that folder, and that gave the same issue

Comment: Under which user is the program running? This could be causing the issue.

Answer (score -1):

This happened to me . I had had an anti-virus blocking access to any file when the writing or reading process happening from a C# program. I have just deactivated the anti-virus and the code worked like magic !

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30805403)